# Excel - How to "combine" columns for a row, and create duplicate rows for the values in the combined columns?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a table like below:

```
Account# Code1 Code2 Code3    
123      A     B     C
```

And I would like to removed columns "Code2" and "Code3", and create new rows like below:

```
Account# Code    
123      A    
123      B    
123      C
```

Unfortunately I'm not sure what this would be called, and every search for "converting columns to rows" turns up with transposing results. Is there some excel function that I can use instead of copying the rows and manually doing it?

Comment: It is called 'Flatten' or 'Unpivot' and can be done following one of the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541905/convert-matrix-to-3-column-table-reverse-pivot-unpivot-flatten-normal

Answer (score 1):

With your data in cols **A** through **C**, in **F1** enter:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$9999,ROUNDUP(ROW()/3,0))
```

and copy down.  In **G1** enter:

```
=OFFSET($B$2,ROUNDUP(ROWS($2:2)/3,0)-1,MOD(ROWS($2:2)-1,3))
```

and copy downwards:

[image]

Comment: Nice one working with lil modifications,,, +10 ☺

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Dynamic Array approach using LET to make it easier to understand, modify and debug.

```
=LET( unPivMatrix, A2:A4,
      byMatrix, B2:D4,
       upC, COLUMNS( unPivMatrix ),
       upCells, MIN( ROWS( unPivMatrix ), ROWS( byMatrix ) ) * upC,
       upSeq, SEQUENCE( upCells,, 0 ),
       byC, COLUMNS( byMatrix ),
       mux, INDEX( unPivMatrix, upSeq/upC + 1, MOD( upSeq, upC ) + 1 ),
       demux, IFERROR( INDEX( byMatrix,
                              IFERROR( INT( SEQUENCE( upCells, byC,0 )/byC/upC ) + 1,
                                       MOD( upSeq, upC ) + 1 ),
                              SEQUENCE( 1, byC + 1 ) ),
                        mux ),
       demux
     )
```

The **unPivMatrix** are the columns you want to distribute - so these would be the **Account#** in your example.  The **byMatrix** are the columns you want to unpivot them by - these would be **Codes** in your example.  Think about a Pivot Table in excel. The **byMatrix** are the rows that you are pivoting the data by and the **unPivMatrix** are the data that you want to unpivot.

This formula first creates a shape for the unpivot, so that it can be multiplexed into a single column (called **mux**) like this:

| mux |
| --- |
| A |
| B |
| C |
| D |
| E |
| F |
| ... |

The result is put into **demux** which first creates an array of the **byMatrix** that repeats the **byMatrix** column values for each column in the **unPivMatrix**

| demux col1 |
| --- |
| 123 |
| 123 |
| 123 |
| 456 |
| 456 |
| 456 |
| 789 |

By referencing one more column than what actually exists in **byMatrix**, the INDEX function throws an error.

| demux col1 | extra column |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | #REF! |
| 123 | #REF! |
| 123 | #REF! |
| 456 | #REF! |
| 456 | #REF! |
| 456 | #REF! |
| 789 | #REF! |

This error is exploited to effectively fuse the two arrays (**demux** of **byMatrix** and **mux**) together. By wrapping the result in an IFERROR, we are able to replace the #REF! error with the values from **mux**.

| demux col1 | extra column |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | A |
| 123 | B |
| 123 | C |
| 456 | D |
| 456 | E |
| 456 | F |
| 789 | G |

This formula is now a general purpose unpivot based on dynamic arrays.  i.e. you can put any range into **unPivMatrix** and **byMatrix** and get the result you want in much the way that UNPIVOT works in Power Query.